# Accessing a JavaScript array using a value passed into a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, checkbox

I have a JavaScript array declared in my JavaScript page like so:

```
var example = [[20,870,5,1,1,16],[28,1250,8,1,1,23]];
```

This works fine when accessed elsewhere.

I have a checkbox in my HTML page like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="example" onChange="update('example')">Example
```

I want the function to look something like below. The variable being passed is also the name of my JS array. I will have 20-30 check boxes and I would ideally like to avoid a load of if/else statements.

```
function update(a) {

alert(a[0][1]);

}
```

Is there anyway to use the variable passed into my function to access the namesake JS array?

Thanks

Comment: You mean like `update(example)` ? This is very bad code design though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `example` is defined, you can remove quotes surrounding parameter `example` at `update(example)` call

```html
<script>
  var example = [
    [20, 870, 5, 1, 1, 16],
    [28, 1250, 8, 1, 1, 23]
  ];

  function update(a) {
    alert(a[0][1]);
  }
</script>

<input type="checkbox" id="example" onchange="update(example)">Example
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function update(a) {
    alert(window[a][0][1]);
}
```